# Unable to use h:components to display text in JQueryUI Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, jsp-tags

I'm trying to create JQueryUI dialog in JSF. I have included the dialog code inside the < div > < /div > in the parent page as shown in JQueryUI Dialog demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form. When I use normal HTML tags like < label > or < input> I'am able to display the required text in the dialog but when I try to use h components like h:outputLabel, h:outputText, then the text is displayed in the parent page instead of the dialog.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The symptoms indicate that you're using the ancient JSF 1.0 or 1.1. Is this true?

Comment: Yes Sir, I'am using JSF 1.1. Is there a way that I can use h components in JQueryUI dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ancient JSF 1.0/1.1, you need to wrap plain vanilla HTML elements in `<f:verbatim>`.

E.g.

```
<f:verbatim><div></f:verbatim>
    <h:inputText ... />
<f:verbatim></div></f:verbatim>
```

Only since JSF 1.2 it's possible to embed plain vanilla HTML elements in a JSF view without the need to hassle with `<f:verbatim>`. You might want to consider upgrading to JSF 1.2 or, better, JSF 2.0.

Comment: **All** plain HTML elements in the JSF page inside `<f:view>` must be wrapped in `<f:verbatim>`. Otherwise, replace them by JSF components.